# Templated class operator+ overloading return type

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to built a templated num class. This class needs to have a public  attribute, `val`, with type `T`, which is the only templated parameter. Furthermore if one provides a value the attribute (`val`) should be initialized with this value. To do so I made the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Num {
public: 
    T val;

    Num():val(0) { std::cout<<"default constr used"<<std::endl; }
    Num(T value):val(value) {std::cout<<"constr (T value) used"<<std::endl; }
    ~Num() { std::cout<<"destructor used"<<std::endl; }

    template<typename U>
    Num operator+(const Num<U>& other) {
        return val+other.value;
    }
};
```

Furthermore I created the `main()` function to test the program, which looks like this:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << Num<int>(1) + Num<double>(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

However the result of the program is now `3`. Whereas I expected it to be `3.0` (of type `double`).

Comment: If you want double as you have the code written now, you'll need to do flip those operands. `Num<int>(1) + Num<double>(2.0);` is the same as `Num<int>(1).operator+(Num<double>(2.0))` which you've declared as returning a value of type `Num<int>`.

Comment: This won't even compile as it is.

Comment: Why would that give a compile error?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez Because the class does not have a member variable named `value`.

Comment: You're right, didn't see that.

Answer (score 10):

For that you will need to change the return type.

In your code:

```
// vvv---- Means Num<T>
   Num operator+(const Num<U>& other) {
       return val + other.val;
   }
```

Indeed, inside a class template, you can type the name of the class without template arguments and it's gonna be somewhat equivalent to writing `Num<T>`.

Your function is always returning the type of the first operant, no matter the type of the addition itself.

What you want is to deduce that type coming from the addition:

```
auto operator+(const Num<U>& other) -> Num<decltype(val + other.val)> {
    return val + other.val;
}
```

That way, it's always the right return type according to the C++ operator rules.

Comment: in c++14 and later, you do not need `-> Num<decltype(val + other.val)>`

Comment: @BЈовић, he does need it. Otherwise, the return type would be `decltype(val + other.val)`, and not `Num<decltype(val + other.val)>`.

Comment: @BЈовић In C++17 I would use return type deduction and class template argument deduction to return `Num{val + other.val}`

Answer (score 9):

`operator+` should be symmetric with respect to its arguments. It's better be implemented as a free function rather than a member function to make this symmetry explicit.

For example (using C++14 return type deduction):

```
template<class T, class U>
auto operator+(const Num<T>& x, const Num<U>& y) {
    using R = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>());
    return Num<R>{x.val + y.val};
}
```

`std::declval<T>()` is there for [genericity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval), if `T` and/or `U` are not default constructible. If types are limited to built-in ones, like `int` and `double`, it can be replaced with `T{}` or `T()`:

```
using R = decltype(T{} + U{});
```

With [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) in C++17 it can be simplified further:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto operator+(const Num<T>& x, const Num<U>& y) {
    return Num{x.val + y.val};
}
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea that you could `auto` away a return type. This is pretty cool.

Comment: @scohe001, it's C++14 feature.